# Passing user inputs directly in python

Tags: python, input, command-line

I have a python script which takes several inputs from users on several menus. I want to pass these inputs directly from say a file or command line. It will be something like for example, 2,Adam and 1234. Now, one way is that I parse the command line and use the parameters but that will need lot of code changes (I want to make minimal changes to code). Is there something I can do with minimal or no changes to the code, as in something which tells the script these will be your inputs, when asked for.

Comment: We will only know if an approach has a *minimal* code change if we know what is the code

Comment: I basically want the raw_input() which is asked in the script  multiple times to be passed directly without user having to enter it.

Comment: Parsing the arguments passed via command lines wil be minimal. Instead of having multiple raw_inputs(), you have args[1], args[2] instead.

Comment: The thing is, I want to ssh and run the whole script through command line and the script has multiple raw_inputs. I am not allowed to edit this file.

Comment: If you're not allowed to edit the file, then I don't see what can be done.